# Are the eigenvalues of projectors always zero and/or one?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, projection-operator

Nielsen and Chuang, page 87, defining projective measurements, refers to projectors with "eigenvalue m." However, exercise 2.16 on page 70 seems to imply that the eigenvalue is always one or zero. This would reduce equation 2.102 to a simple sum.

Are the eigenvalues always zero or one?

What does this imply for equation 2.102 (defn of projective measurements)

Comment: The eigenvalue of $P_m$ is either $0$ or $1$, yes. This is from the fact that $P_m^2 = P_m$. In the formula $\sum_m mP_m$, $m$ are the eigenvalues of $M$ and not $P_m$.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1157589/173147

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalues of projectors are always 0 or 1 (a projector satisfies $P^2=P$, which is equivalent to the eigenvalues satisfying $\lambda^2=\lambda$).

This does not have any implication for equation (2.102) in Nielsen & Chuang. The point is that they are defining a new operator
$$
M=\sum_mmP_m,
$$
requiring that $P_iP_j=\delta_{ij}P_i$.
They make no claim that $M$ is a projector, it is an *observable*. In general, it is not a projector, and it has eigenvalues $\{m\}$. It's simply that there is a very convenient decomposition in terms of projectors, which goes both ways: if I know the projectors, I can construct $M$. But, more importantly, if you give me an $M$, I can use this to extract the $\{P_m\}$ (just find the eigenvectors of $M$), and this defines my measurement projectors.

To see this, imagine that there's a state $|\psi\rangle$ for which $P_i|\psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle$ and $P_j|\psi\rangle=0$ for all $j\neq i$. Then
$$
M|\psi\rangle=i|\psi\rangle,
$$
so $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $i$.